# How can I replace empty elements in an array with "OTHER"?

Tags: perl, arrays, list

My list (@degree) is built from a SQL command. The NVL command in the SQL isn't working, neither are tests such as:

```
if (@degree[$i] == "")
if (@degree[$i] == " ")
if (@degree[$i] == '')
if (@degree[$i] == -1)
if (@degree[$i] == 0)
if (@degree[$i] == ())
if (@degree[$i] == undef)
```

$i is a counter variable in a for loop. Basically it goes through and grabs unique degrees from a table and ends up creating `("AFA", "AS", "AAS", "", "BS")`. The list is not always this long, and the empty element is not always in that position 3.

Can anyone help?

I want to either test during the for loop, or after the loop completes for where this empty element is and then replace it with the word, "OTHER".

Thanks for anything
-Ken

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the ith element in an array is $degree[$i], not @degree[$i].  Second, "==" is for numerical comparisons - use "eq" for lexical comparisons.  Third of all, try `if (defined($degree[$i]))`

Comment: thanks... ya i know its $degree[$i], i was just in a rush haha

and the eq worked perfectly... I'm just learning perl on my own and i couldnt find this answer anywhere so thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

Everything that Paul said.  And, if you need an example:

```
my @degree = ('AFA', 'AS', 'AAS', '', 'BS');

$_ ||= 'OTHER' for @degree;

print join ' ' => @degree;  # prints 'AFA AS AAS OTHER BS'
```

Answer (score 1):

If its actually a null in the database, try `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(column, 'no value') AS column FROM whatever ...
```

That's the SQL-standard way to do it.